# Cannot find android.net.ProxyProperties class

Tags: android, proxy

I am trying to change proxy in my **android webview**. In there, I need to send `ProxyProperties` within bundle. But I cannot find `ProxyProperties` class in android API. 
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

ProxyProperties was replaced with ProxyInfo.  See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ProxyInfo.html